# What was the first work to portray the guardian of the Golden Fleece as a many-headed hydra?

Tags: history-of, dragons, mythology

At the climax of the mythical tale of Jason and the Argonauts' voyage to Colchis, Jason (with the help of the local priestess-princess Medea) steals the Golden Fleece from a sacred grove, where it hung from a tree and was guarded by the [Colchian dragon](http://www.argonauts-book.com/the-dragon.html).  He put the dragon to sleep and took the fleece from the tree.

One of the best-known depictions of this comes from the movie *Jason and the Argonauts* (1963), in which the dragon is depicted as forked-tailed, hydra-like creature with seven heads (prefiguring the number of skeletons that would be grown from from its teeth by King Aeetes).

However, Ray Harryhausen's seven-headed monster does not match the way the the dragon that guarded the Golden Fleece was usually described and shown.  It was normally depicted in ancient times as serpentine, as in [this famous Attic stemmed bowl (kylix) in the collection of the Vatican Museums](https://m.museivaticani.va/content/museivaticani-mobile/en/collezioni/musei/museo-gregoriano-etrusco/sala-xix--emiciclo-inferiore--collezione-dei-vasi--ceramica-atti/kylix-attica-attribuita-a-douris--giasone.html),

[image: Dragon disgorging Jason before Athena]

or this vase from Apulia in [Magna Graecia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magna_Graecia).

[image: Roman vase]

In more recent times, pictures of the dragon has still generally been shown it with just a single head.

However, the idea of a Colchian dragon being a many-headed hydra does not seem to have originated with *Jason and the Argonauts* either.  Something qualitatively similar shows up in the 1948 novel [*The Mask of Circe*](https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_Canadian_Ed._v17n02_1948-05/page/n11/mode/2up) by Henry Kuttner.

[image: Python tree]

> Legend records that the Golden Fleece hangs on a tree guarded by an unsleeping dragon.  How much less than truth was in the legend I could see as my eyes adjusted to that aching glare.  It was an allegory, indeed, but the truth was far stranger than the legend.
>
> I saw the Fleece.  It was hard to focus on in all that blaze of shimmering fire, but I could make out the shape of it vaguely, pure gold, burning like the flowers with an unconsuming flame.  I could see the ringlets of its pelt, white-hot, delicately curling wires that stirred slightly when the tree stirred.
>
> There was no python in the garden, no scaled guardian. The tree itself was the dragon.
>
> I saw the sluggish writhing of its boughs, gold-scaled, flexible, sliding over one another in an endless, sleepless stirring.  There were no leaves, but every limb was tipped with a flat triangular head that watched unwinkingly in the glare of the burning garden.

The idea that the "tree at the end of the world" is itself the guardian dragon is rather clever, but the description seems to assume the reasonableness of the the dragon having many heads.  It seems unlikely that Kuttner invented this part of the depiction.

So where did the idea of the hydra-like dragon guarding the fleece originate?  What was the first work that portrayed the creature this way—with many heads?

Comment: In other words, who was the first author to confuse Jason and Heracles? ;-)

Comment: "the description seems to assume the reasonableness of the the dragon having many heads" The hydra was a well-known existing Greek mythological creature (as DavidW alludes to, one of the twelve labors of Hercules was to kill a hydra that kept growing new heads each time one was chopped off), so I would disagree with your point that Kuttner's assuming the reader would accept this without much explanation makes it unlikely that Kuttner invented the idea of putting it in the Golden Fleece story, though of course it's still possible he borrowed it from an earlier writer or artist.

Comment: Note it wasn't "a hydra" Heracles killed, but The Hydra - a specific one-of-a-kind monster, living at Lerna.  Not a member of a species.

Comment: Not an answer because it dates from 2010, but in Marvel's 2010 comic book "Dark Avengers: Ares", Ares's son Kyknos uses the teeth of Hydra soldiers to grow skeletons. Ares explains that this is supposed to be done with the teeth of the actual Hydra, but that magic works with symbols, so the teeth of soldiers from the Hydra organisation work too.